# VBA Excel vlookup error

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I've written a macro that will print out guest letters, based on their spoken language and name:

```
Sub VIPbrieven()

'change printersettings here

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

'print letters
'set ranges

'this range contains 4 columns; the first column contains the languague, the third contains the salutation, the fourth the word 'guest' in said alnguages
Dim gasten As Range
Set gasten = Range("r8:u13")

'this is the guestlist, containing the guest's names and languages
Dim Lijst As Range
Set Lijst = Range("a8:p120")

Dim kamers As Range
Set kamers = Range("a8:a120")

'only rows containing information need to be checked
Dim rij As Double
For rij = 1 To kamers.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

'this is supposed to look for the right salutation. works perfecty when i copy just this line to another macro
Range("s20").Value = Application.VLookup(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value, gasten, 3, False)

Dim aanspreking As String
    aanspreking = Range("s20").Value

'groups come with drivers and/or guides, we don't know their names. in those cases we just put 'guest' in said language
If Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "Guide" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "Drive" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "guide" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "drive" Then

    Dim naam As String
    naam = Application.VLookup(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value, gasten, 4, False)

    If IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 2)) = False Then
    With Sheets(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value)
        .Range("b20").Value = StrConv(aanspreking & " " & naam & ",", 3)
        .PrintOut
    End With
    End If
'if we do know their names, we just put the name
    Else

    Dim naam2 As String
    naam2 = Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value


    If IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 2)) = False Then
    With Sheets(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value)
        .Range("b20").Value = StrConv(aanspreking2 & " " & naam2 & ",", 3)
        .PrintOut
    End With
    End If
End If


Next rij

Range("s20").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Whenever I execute it, I get an error on this line

```
aanspreking = Range("s20").Value
```

it's the line above:

```
Range("s20").Value = Application.VLookup(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value, gasten, 3, False)
```

...that causes the error. I split in in two lines so I could see what result it returns, and it returns #N/B.

When i copy that line to another macro and execute it, I get the correct value. I'm totally clueless... Anyone?

Comment: This is your fifth question since April 27. On the previous four you didn't accept a response and you didn't award points for comments. Perhaps helping you isn't good business.

Comment: Very likely, your problem relates to the sheet on which `gasten` is located. Your code defines it as being on the `ActiveSheet` (which is the default since you don't specify any). Therefore you are likely to have different results depending upon which sheet happens to be active when you run the code. Solve the problem by avoiding the `ActiveSheet`, whether by default or by name.

Comment: I've asked 8 questions since that date actually, of which I've deleted 2. of those 8 questions, i've had only three answered, of which i accepted two, and have yet to test the third one but i can only do so when at my second job (in two weeks). And i can't award points for comments (yet?)

should i answer my own questions when smth is solved, wether i solved it myself or with the help of someone who commented (rather than answer)?

I'll try replacing `ActiveSheet` with `HSK` (the name of the sheet in question) as soon as I'm back at work...

Comment: Yes. If you found a solution to your own question you should publish it. It will help someone just as well as might the answer of anyone else.

Comment: and i publish it the same way as i ask a question?

Comment: No, you publish your answer in the same way as I publish mine. You will find a button at the bottom of the screen which says "Answer your own question". Was my above suggestion about your problem helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I'll get on it right away.

I am yet to check it out, I'll be back at work on thursday. I'll get back to you as soon as I tested it.

Comment: I checked it, and that was indeed where it went wrong. I added an If Not statement to prevent errors from occurring when there's an empty cell (whenever a guest does not receive a VIP letter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the range not being defined as being on the specific sheets it's on, as @Variatus suggested.

The code below now successfully print the letters like it's intended to. I added

```
If Not IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16)) Then
```

Because otherwise if there was an ampty cell the macro would return an error.

```
Sub VIPbrieven()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'change printersettings here

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

'print letters
'set ranges

'this range contains 4 columns; the first column contains the languague, the third contains the salutation, the fourth the word 'guest' in said alnguages
Dim gasten As Range
Set gasten = Sheets("HKG").Range("r8:u13")

'this is the guestlist, containing the guest's names and languages
Dim Lijst As Range
Set Lijst = Sheets("HKG").Range("a8:p120")

Dim kamers As Range
Set kamers = Sheets("HKG").Range("a8:a120")

'only rows containing information need to be checked
Dim rij As Double
For rij = 1 To kamers.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

'this is supposed to look for the right salutation. works perfecty when i copy just this line to another macro
If Not IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16)) Then
Sheets("HKG").Range("s20").Value = Application.VLookup(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value, gasten, 3, False)



'groups come with drivers and/or guides, we don't know their names. in those cases we just put 'guest' in said language
If Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "Guide" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "Drive" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "guide" Or Left(Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value, 5) = "drive" Then

    Dim aanspreking As String
    aanspreking = Sheets("HKG").Range("s20").Value

    Dim naam As String
    naam = Application.VLookup(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value, gasten, 4, False)

    If IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 2)) = False Then
    With Sheets(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value)
        .Range("b20").Value = StrConv(aanspreking & " " & naam & ",", 3)
        .PrintOut
    End With
    End If

'if we do know their names, we just put the name
Else

    Dim naam2 As String
    naam2 = Lijst.Cells(rij, 15).Value

    Dim aanspreking2 As String
    aanspreking2 = Sheets("HKG").Range("s20").Value

    If IsEmpty(Lijst.Cells(rij, 2)) = False Then
    With Sheets(Lijst.Cells(rij, 16).Value)
        .Range("b20").Value = StrConv(aanspreking2 & " " & naam2 & ",", 3)
        .PrintOut
    End With
    End If
End If

End If
Next rij


Sheets("HKG").Range("s20").ClearContents
Sheets("HKG").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```